# IBM-containers: Retrieving client certificate for IBM containers failed

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I am a newbie to Bluemix and have problems with containers. I installed Docker Toolbox (my OS is Windows 7). Afterwards I installed Bluemix plugin IBM-containers. (I checked both installations, everything seemed fine to me.) Then I logged into Bluemix (cf login -a ...). And then I run command: cf ic login. And I got an error message
[image]

I've tried to deploy a sample java application to Bluemix before. It worked OK, I did not encounter any network connection problems. I don't understand what is the cause of the error.

Any ideas what could be the problem or how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solutions yet? (2017) @Zelphir, etc

Comment: @LeonardPauli I think in the end I created a new account (it's like Windows restart - magic). However, today a year later, I am hitting this problem again and there is still no working answer to this issue. *sigh* one would think they are able to get their story straight, but nope …

Answer (score 0):

You need to login using:

```
 ice login -k API_KEY -R registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
```

Source: [Alaa Youssef on DeveloperWorks](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/167390/unable-to-get-a-success-authentication-with-bluemi.html#answer-167549)

Comment: However, I cannot find any api key on my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time you use the container service you may need to run the `cf ic init` and the `cf ic namespace set` commands. Take a look [here](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__namespace) for more information.

If your registry is already configured, please always remember to do a `cf login` just before doing a `cf ic login`. If the problem persists and you are able to access containers service from your Bluemix Dashboard, you could try to use the new [bx CLI](http://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/home.html) (that wraps the *ic* plugin).

Comment: I run the      cf ic init    and I got an error: _Generating client certificates for IBM containers failed. Error, getting response, check your network connection_. I tried to set a namespace, and again: _Error, getting response, check your network connection_ . I wanted to check, if the namespace wasn't (by any chance) set before. I run the    cf ic namespace get. I got: _Error on loading client key pair_. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to use the Bluemix (bx)  CLI?

Comment: I tried to use Bluemix CLI, and I got the network connection error again.

Comment: Same here, Error on loading client key pair. It then suggests to run `cf ic init` which does not help at all. Then I tried to login again, no change.